# Only one array result showing outside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In the code below I am using `var_export` to document the information being imported,  However the e-mail is only showing one object within the `$values` variable outside of the foreach loop.

How can I make it so that I can get my expected result?

**Pauls:**

```
$values = [];

foreach ($guests as $k => $guest)
{

  $values[$k] = array(
   'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
   'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
   'Email' => $guest['email'],
   'Country' => $guest['country'],
   '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
   '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
  );
```

**E-Mail Result:**

```
array (
  'FirstName' => 'Test 1',
  'LastName' => 'Test 2',
  'Email' => '',
  'Country' => 'New Zealand',
  '_CheckIn' => '2017-04-25',
  '_CheckOut' => '2017-04-27',
)
```

**Expected E-mail Result** -  as per `$values` `var_dump`

```
array (
  'FirstName' => 'Test 1',
  'LastName' => 'Test 2',
  'Email' => '',
  'Country' => 'New Zealand',
  '_CheckIn' => '2017-04-25',
  '_CheckOut' => '2017-04-27',
)
array (
  'FirstName' => 'Test 1',
  'LastName' => 'Test 2',
  'Email' => '',
  'Country' => 'New Zealand',
  '_CheckIn' => '2017-04-25',
  '_CheckOut' => '2017-04-27',
)
array (
  'FirstName' => 'Test 1',
  'LastName' => 'Test 2',
  'Email' => '',
  'Country' => 'New Zealand',
  '_CheckIn' => '2017-04-25',
  '_CheckOut' => '2017-04-27',
)
```

**Code:**

```
    $values = [];
    foreach ($guests as $guest)
    {

      $values = array(
       'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
       'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
       'Email' => $guest['email'],
       'Country' => $guest['country'],
       '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
       '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
      );


     //inserting guestst to Contact table
        $optInEmail  = $values['Email'];
        $optInReason = 'Purchased Accommodation';


        $tagID = '566'; //
        $contactID = $infusionsoft->contacts()->addWithDupCheck($values,'Email');
        $infusionsoft->contacts()->addToGroup($contactID, $tagID);
        $infusionsoft->emails()->optIn($optInEmail, $optInReason);

     echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($values);
     echo "</pre>";    

    }


    if(empty($values))
    {
        echo '<h1>No new Data</h1>';
    }else{
    $from    = "API";
    $to      = "";
    $subject = "API Import"." ".date("h:i:sa")." ".date("d-m-Y");
    $message = var_export($values, true);
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers))
    {
        echo '<h1>E-mail Sent Data Imported</h1>';

    }else{
        echo "What Broke Boss";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I debug by email some variable.

```
mail($to,$subject,print_r($variable,true));
```

var_export is printing the object because this function can not handle reference cycles/recursive arrays.

Here is a post about the [differences between var_export and print_r](https://web-profile.net/php/dev/var_dump-print_r-var_export/) (and var_dump that is useful too).

Comment: Thanks but its still giving me the single result

Comment: Ohh that's because you are overwriting the $values array.

Edit the foreach:
`foreach ($guests as $k => $guest)`

Then, in the $values:
`$values[$k] = array(...)`

This should work.

Comment: Correct I just cant click/ Over thinking how to fix it

Comment: Thanks,  However it breaks the code - no specific error - I am using infusionsoft for a section and its "No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;, java.lang.String'" - I have updated my question with what I have

Comment: Does the error occur with this new change? 
I don't know what infusionsoft does but I think is a different issue.

Comment: Yes just with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand what the ask is. Please rephrase what you would like the expected outcome to be.

Please review this section of code

```
$values = array(
    'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
    'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
    'Email' => $guest['email'],
    'Country' => $guest['country'],
   '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
   '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
  );
```

On the foreach, the variable $values is being completely replaced with the array that you just created. Perhaps you meant to do something like

```
$values[] = array(
    'FirstName' => $guest['FirstName'],
    'LastName' => $guest['LastName'],
    'Email' => $guest['email'],
    'Country' => $guest['country'],
    '_CheckIn' => $guest['check-in_date'],
    '_CheckOut' => $guest['check-out_date'],
);
```

The above code will add the new array to the $values array.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of my current and expected results

Comment: Just got the email from stack overflow, it looks like the info I provided helped you. Congrats.